# hpple parse xml , [element content] always be null

Tags: ios, hpple

1.this is my code

```
NSStringEncoding encoding2 = NSUTF8StringEncoding;
// i am from china
NSString *c1 = @"<html><head><title A='sss'>sss</title></head><body><a href='sssssss这个中文就么哟sa哈aa'>asas</a></body></html>";
htmlData = [c1 dataUsingEncoding:encoding2];
TFHpple *xpathParser = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:htmlData];
NSArray *elements  = [xpathParser searchWithXPathQuery:@"//a"]; 
TFHppleElement *element = [elements objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *myTitle = [element content];
NSLog(@"%@",element.tagName);
NSLog(@"%@",myTitle);
NSString *attr = [element objectForKey:@"href"];
NSLog(@"%@",attr);
```

1. this is the out put

   ```
   **
   2012-08-12 14:59:34.624 HHXY[1506:f803] a
   2012-08-12 14:59:34.625 HHXY[1506:f803] (null)
   2012-08-12 14:59:34.625 HHXY[1506:f803] sssssss这个中文就么哟sa哈aa
   **
   ```

a easy test but the content(myTitle) always be null , i don't know why? help me.be greatly appreciated

Comment: The element 'a' has no title property.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem.

Try to replace this line:

```
NSString *myTitle = [element content];
```

with next:

```
NSString *myTitle = [[element firstChild] content];
```

or change your regular expression:

```
@"//a"
```

with

```
@"//a/text()"
```

I hope that one of these ways will help you!